# How to create numpy ndarray from numpy ndarrays?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

I used the **MNIST** dataset for training a neural network, where the training data is returned as a tuple with two entries. The first entry contains the actual training images. This is a numpy ndarray with 50,000 entries. Each entry is, in turn, a numpy ndarray with 784 values, representing the 28 * 28 = 784 pixels in a single **MNIST** image.

I would like to create a new training set, however I do not know how to create an ndarray from other ndarrays. For instance, if I have the following two ndarrays:

```
a = np.ndarray((3,1), buffer=np.array([0.9,1.0,1.0]), dtype=float)

b = np.ndarray((3,1), buffer=np.array([0.8,1.0,1.0]), dtype=float)
```

how to make a third one containing these two?

I tried the following but it creates only one entry.

```
c = np.ndarray((1,6,1), buffer=np.array(([a],[b])), dtype=float)
```

I would need it to be two entries.

Comment: Does ``np.vstack([a, b])`` do the job?

Comment: np.vstack also creates one entry. c = np.array((a, b)) however seems to work. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Thanks, in the meanwhile I figured out it is simply:

```
c = np.array((a, b))
```